# The url redirecting is failing?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, web-deployment

Its a godaddy root structure where we have to keep all files in the root directory to access the url as www.example.com, and any other domain has to be in the root directory of the primary domain with which the payment is done, pretty crappy structure from go daddy.

To avoid the clutter I made the one more folder inside root as /example/.. and pushed all the files form root to the mentioned folder,

earlier it was working fine, I had purchased ssl certificate but after the certificate expires, it was not opening the domain so I have made the  `rewritecond %{HTTPS} !off` form  `rewritecond %{HTTPS} !on` and now the redirection is not at all working,

I am really bad at .htaccess, so looking for best advice.

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTPS} !off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
rewriterule ^$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/index\.php" [R=301,L] #51w512ed4b49c
rewriterule ^$ "http\:\/\/example\.com" [R=301,L] #51w512ed4b49c


rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 [QSA]
rewritecond %{HTTPS} !off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
rewriterule ^(/)?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I want the redirection from `www.example.com` to `example.com` 
and url should look as `example.com/index.php` or `example.com` not as `example.com/example/index.php` or `example.com/example/`
Now I don't want the SSL and how to update the .htaccess 
Why is internal server error is coming just for the example folder and not for any other folder.

Folder Structure in godaddy panel:

[image]

Comment: Do you plan to use SSL anymore, or now that your cert has expired are you through with it?

Comment: No, not for the time being ...  no ssl anymore now..

Comment: Which directory is this .htaccess in - the root or /example?

Comment: .htaccess is in root directory, it was working fine earlier but after certi expired the redirection is completly gone

Comment: That is suspect, because even if the cert expired it should be possible to continue using it with browser warnings and no changes to .htaccess.  Comment out all the lines that reference HTTPS. What is the purpose of the two rules which match `^$`? Only the first of them will ever be matched.

Comment: I removed all the htaccess, and trying to access the file directly I don't know why it is throwing internal server error,I am getting mad now..
while all other folder are accessible for other domain and manually created folder.. If I access like..

www.example.com/otherdomainfolder/
www.example.com/otherfolder/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63656/discussion-between-stackup-and-michael-berkowski).

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in the inner directories? It sounds like you might.  A 500 internal server error will be detailed inside  the Apache error log, which I assume your web host must provide some access to. Very often, redirection leads to an infinite loop if not carefully handled.  It would help if you edited your question above to show exactly what your directory layout is, and all the domains involved, along with your redirection goals (understood to be removing `www.` from the URL and serving it based on the HTTP_HOST into the correct subdir)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No there is no another .htaccess file apart from this, 
Even if I don't want a redirection it should directly access the file through absolute url but even that is also that is also throwing internal server error.

Updated the ques with folder structure..

Comment: Check the error log to find out what the internal server error was.